# Cannot open Yahoo Messenger chat window in Firefox 9

Tags: firefox, yahoo-messenger

I am using Yahoo Messenger through http://mail.yahoo.com in Firefox 9.0.1 under Windows XP.

In Firefox 8, chat works without problem, but in Firefox 9, I can log in to chat, friend list is populated, but when I click one of my contacts, it doesn't open a chat window (it should). I tried pressing 'i' (keyboard shortcut for new chat), also no chat window.

I tried using Chrome and the chat works in Chrome.

Does anyone know how to make YM chat work with Firefox 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [Mozilla's issue tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=713014): it is a bug in Firefox 9, and they are still looking for the cause. For now, to make the chat window pops up in Firefox 9, do the following:

- Open Options - Messenger Options - General
- Change Conversation Window Management to **Tab**
- Press OK
- Open again Options - Messenger Options - General
- Change Conversation Window Management to **Small Window**
- Press OK

After this, the chat window will pop up. But you have to repeat the procedure the next time you open Yahoo Mail.

OR

- Wait till the page finishes loading, contact list appears on the left with photos
- Try to open Options - Messenger Options (it will fail, option will not open)
- Now when you click a contact, the chat popup will open